# Полноценная работа Contains в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

В базе MSSQL в колонке `Name` есть значение `ООО ПАО Азимут`. Его необходимо найти по маске `ООО зим`.
Я использую полнотекстовый поиск в MSSQL через команду `Contains`.
 Вот мои пример:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Companies 
WHERE (Contains((Name), '"ооо*" AND "зим*"'))  
ORDER BY Id 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

не находит

Comment: а если без `ооо*` или сократить до `оо*` ?

Comment: Это  не имеет значение, так как пользователь может ввести такое значение

Comment: ну вот проиндексирует в этом названии поиск три слова ооо, пао, азмиут.  вы ищите префиксные формы ооо* и зим*, то есть слова начинающиеся с этих букв. в первом случае, оно начинается с `ООО` но тут же и заканчивается, хз будет ли префикс так искать, а во втором с `зим` ничего не начинается. вот и подумайте,  нужны ли тут префиксы вам.

Comment: Что в итоге нужно сделать? Я не совсем понимаю)